# Why is a foreach data binding not creating a $parent context?

Tags: knockout.js

In the following code, why is the `remove` handler accessible without `$parent`?

If I use `data-bind="click: $parent.remove"` I get an error saying that `property remove of undefined doesn't exists`, but being inside a foreach loop, shouldn't I get a `$parent` context?

Template:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:list">
    <li><!-- ko text: $data --><!-- /ko --> <button data-bind="click: remove">x</button></li>
</ul>
```

ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    this.list = ko.observableArray(['asd', 'lol', 'rofl']);

    this.remove = function(index){
        console.log('Clicked ' + index);
        self.list.splice(index, 1);
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3d7nfbr3/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `new`, when creating your viewmodel.

Your code should look like this:

```
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Without the `new` the `this` refers to the global `window` object so your `remove` function is declared globally, that is why the `$parent` is not working.

Demo [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly1n83yu/).